# Ищу алгоритм сортировка событий ( метод сканирующей прямой ), реализация на Java

Tags: java, алгоритм

Подскажите пожалуйста, где можно найти реализацию алгоритма "сортировка событий" на языке Java? Еще его вроде как называют "метод сканирующей прямой".

Comment: По сути это обычная сортировка. Главное - по какому критерию сортировать и как применять, в этом весь цимес. Какая у вас конкретная задача? Посмотрите мои ответы [по слову "интервал"](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A291659+%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BB) и ответы Stanislav Volodarskiy [по слову "заметание"](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A416121+%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)

Comment: Метод сканирующей прямой это не конкретный алгоритм, а схема построения алгоритмов и доказательства их правильности. Схему можно описать словами, едва ли вы отыщите её обобщённую реализацию в виде кода. Поместите в вопрос конкретную задачу, получите конкретную иллюстрацию метода.